# Почему срабатывает событие Click после рендера?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Всем привет. Во время рендера срабатывает собитие `onClick` по каждому выводимому блоку. При нажатии `onClick` не работает.

```
<View style={styles.blockTraining}>
        {
          this.state.events.length > 0 ? (
            this.state.events.map((value) => {
              return <Card onClick={this.navToEvent()} key={value.event.id}>
                <Text style={styles.activeTraining}>{value.event.name}
                </Text>
                <View style={styles.textTraining}>
                  <View>
                    <Text style={styles.valuesTraining}>Старт: {value.event.startDate}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.valuesTraining}>Тренер: {value.event.lector.person.fullname}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.valuesTraining}>Место:</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <Icon
                      name='check'
                      type='evilicon'
                      color='#228B22'
                      size={30}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
              </Card>
            })
          ) : (
            <ActivityIndicator
              size="large"
              color="#EA329A"
              style={styles.loader}
            />
          )
        }
      </View>
```

Comment: скобки уберите тут `this.navToEvent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему срабатывает событие `onClick` после рендера? Или почему функция вызывается каждый раз при отрисовке компонента? Всё достаточно просто, ответ следует ниже.

Убедитесь, что вы не вызываете функцию, когда передаёте её компоненту:

```
// Неправильно: вместо ссылки была вызвана функция navToEvent
<Card onClick={this.navToEvent()} />
```

Вместо этого передайте саму функцию (без скобок):

```
// Правильно: функция navToEvent передаётся как ссылка
<Card onClick={this.navToEvent} />
```

Полезные ссылки:

- [Передача функций в компоненты](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

  - [Как передать обработчик события (например, onClick) компоненту?](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-an-event-handler-like-onclick-to-a-component)
  - [Как привязать функцию к экземпляру компонента?](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance)
  - [Можно ли использовать стрелочные функции в методе render()?](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#is-it-ok-to-use-arrow-functions-in-render-methods)
  - [Зачем вообще нужна привязка?](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-binding-necessary-at-all)
  - [**Почему моя функция вызывается каждый раз при отрисовке компонента?**](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-my-function-being-called-every-time-the-component-renders)
  - [Как передать параметры обработчику событий или колбэку?](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-or-callback)
  - [Как предотвратить слишком быстрый или слишком частый вызов функции?](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-can-i-prevent-a-function-from-being-called-too-quickly-or-too-many-times-in-a-row)
- [Обработка событий](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

  - [Передача аргументов в обработчики событий](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)